# how to get specific value in xml parsing by write in edittext

Tags: android

i found this tutorial which show xml parsing but is show all values in xml file on 1st screen i want tomodify this code and add edittextbox which show only that value attributes which name i type on edit textbox supose i type in edit text box 2  so is show on screen only ID 2 atttributes not all data show on screen how i connect edittext box with database so is show only selected item on screen??

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can , in the code section below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID).equals(et.getText().toString())){
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
}else{
 }
```

As you can see , you just retrieve the id from XML and compare it to the id you get from the Edit text. If they match add it to the  hashmap else dont !

Hope this helps!

Comment: where i close this bracket?

  if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID).equals(et.getText().toString())){

end of this line is open bracket wheere i close?

Comment: is not compile  xml layout is not allow to add edittext in mainxml file