# Code does not compile?

Tags: android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get specific value in xml parsing by write in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283454/how-to-get-specific-value-in-xml-parsing-by-write-in-edittext)

This code does not compile whats wrong in this code? Is not say  application stop unexpectedly  did I do correctly everything? Please check it I want to add an `EditText` which take input and check its value from `XML` file and show on screen I followed  [this Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

```
      static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
       EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

               ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new 
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
           if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID).equals(et.getText().toString())){

            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
            }

      }
        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
                // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) 
       view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  
    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml file-->>

```
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Main ListView 
     Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
-->

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="596dp" />



    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283454/how-to-get-specific-value-in-xml-parsing-by-write-in-edittext)?

Comment: have you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: in last question i ask how to search edittext value with xml file but in this code when i add edittext in main.xml file is not run and code is blast

Comment: not compiling? what error are you getting. be more specific

Comment: the sample code is working fine but when i add edittext in main.xml file is not show on preview also when i run code is say applictaion stop unexpectedly

Comment: so did you add internet permission as @NiravRanpara pointed?

Comment: the sample code main.xml file   not allow to add edittext in main.xml file

Comment: yes i download his code is  working fine but is not allow me to add edittext in main.xml file

Comment: you probably get NetworkOnUIThread exception. The network operations must be done on a separate thread

Comment: is not aprse any value when i add edittext in main.cml tell me why

Comment: which exception is coming? post your logcat for more details

Comment: no exception  but when i run sample code is work fine but when i add edittext in main.xml  is not show on  Grapical layout  and also no any data show when run this code on screen

Comment: when i  modify with above xml whos u paste on above  the exception come in log Your content must have a listView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list

Comment: did u see sample code in url? i want  show edittext view in 1st screen and when i write any id like 2 ,3 ,4 is display only selected value attribut on 2nd activity   do not diosplay all content on 1st activity how do i do that??   how to remove list in 1st screen?

Comment: Be specific. Is your edit text is not visible on the screen or you are not getting any data in your edit text.?

Comment: just tell me how i remove listview form 1st screen ?? and display only edittextview?

Comment: i  modify my code just tell me or edit this code so remove all list view from 1st screen only leave edittext view  and when i enter any value in edit textview like 2,3  is display on 2nd screen only that value not all

Comment: i only want remove every thing on 1st screen not display anythids except edittext and when i write any ID in edittext like 2,3  is display on 2nd screen only that value attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
               EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new 
             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                   if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID).equals(et.getText().toString())){
                       String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);
                       String cost = "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST);
                       String description = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC);
                       Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                       in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                       in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                       in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                       startActivity(in);
                    }

              }
    }
```

and in the `SingleMenuItemActivity` class, fetch the values using,

```
    String name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY_NAME");
String cost= this.getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY_NAME");
String description= this.getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY_DESC");
```

**Edit-**

main.xml file-->>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Extend your Activity from the `Activity` class

Comment: what abour main.xml file? how i change that??

Comment: the acitivity is extented by ListActivity  also    The value of the local variable menuItems is not used

Answer (score 0):

Your layout.xml is not properly formed:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10" >
```

You need to properly end the `<EditText>` tag with **`/>`** like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: is again show blank on screen   how do i remove list values in 1st screen  in main.xml file

Comment: if i remove  listview in main.xml file  the application stop unexpectedly

Comment: the acitivity is extented by ListActivity  also    The value of the local variable menuItems is not used